# PHP MySql delete query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a delete script on my dashboard that WAS working before moving domains.

( not sure if that is relevant )

The code for my 'deletejob.php' is below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;
$database = 'database';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$UID = $_POST["ID"];


// Connect to the database    
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); // connect

$Query = "DELETE FROM joblist WHERE ID='$UID'";
// Do a query thingy whatever its called
$statement = $db->prepare($Query);
$statement->execute();
while ($result = $statement->fetchObject()) {}

?>
```

The script functions as if it is working and even gives me the alert 
( ID has been successfully deleted. )

Does anyone have any idea as to why this script would return a false positive?

Comment: Not much use of using prepared statements if you just paste the value straight into your query...

Comment: where is your alert code?on which basis you shows the alert?

Comment: Can we see your form? Since there is no error checking in your code how should it alert you?

Comment: Why are you using prepared statements when you are manually inserting them into the query?

Comment: I`m not sure prepare->execute works with pasted variables.And why do you use fetchObject on DELETE?

Comment: you are vulnerable to sql injections like `0 OR '1' = '1`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NL0t6vCb

Comment: @V5Nathan Try changing `$_POST["ID"]` to `$_POST["ItemUID"]`.

Comment: @Ivar Still nothing after changing to your suggestion. Still getting the ID has been successfully deleted message though.

Comment: [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns false if the statement fails. Try to do something like this: `if (!$statement->execute()){header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"); }`

Comment: What objects do you expect to retrieve from the database when you run a `DELETE` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must find the row you want to delete, using SELECT statement, like this:

```
$stmt= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['ids']."'");
```

Also You have to have the following sent when you click the delete button or it will not delete at all:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['ids'];?>">
```

After the above:

```
$stmt= $conn->query("DELETE FROM users Where id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'");
```